# Incrementing score in Python CGI

Tags: python, cgi

I am having some trouble getting my score's to increment. It works but it keeps resetting to zero after the first "+1" has been done.

```
user1score = 0
user2score = 0

def main():
    if form.has_key('choice'):
        myMove = form['choice'].value
        cpuM = computerMove()
        result = compareMove(myMove, cpuM)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        writeFile(user, result, now)
        show(user)
        print user
        print now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        print result



    else:
        show(user)



def computerMove():
    cc = ["rock","scissor","paper"]
    return random.choice(cc)



def compareMove(myMove, cpuM):
    global user1score
    global user2score
    if myMove == cpuM:
        return "Its a tie!"
    elif myMove == 'rock':
        if cpuM == 'paper':
            user2score += 1
            return "Paper beats Rock. Computer wins! " + str(user2score)
        else:
            user1score += 1
            return "Rock beats Scissors. You win! " + str(user1score)
    elif myMove == 'paper':
        if cpuM == 'rock':
            user1score += 1
            return "Paper beats Rock. You win! " + str(user1score)
        else:
            user2score += 1
            return "Scissors beats paper. Computer wins! " + str(user2score)
    elif myMove == 'scissors':
        if cpuM == 'rock':
            user2score += 1
            return "Rock beats scissors. Computer wins " + str(user2score)
        else:
            user1score += 1
            return "Scissors beats paper. You win " + str(user1score)
```

How can i prevent the score from returning to zero after the score is increased by 1? Everything else is working as intended.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this script get called each time the user makes a move?

Comment: It does indeed.

Comment: write value in file or database.

Comment: So why is it surprising that the globals get reset? Consider storing  `user1score` & `user2score` in a file on the server. You _could_ store them as hidden fields in your form, but that's just too easy for an enterprising user to hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your script is called every time the user does something, it can't rembember the result of the previous rounds.

Either use some kind of a *session*(cookie) or *add the scores to your form* as hidden elements.